# How to create a random networkx graph with random weights

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I am attempting to create a random networkx graph with each edge having a random weight (representing length).

At the moment I am using the `gnm_random_graph` function from the set of [`networkx` graph generators](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generators.html#module-networkx.generators.random_graphs):

```
g=nx.gnm_random_graph(5,5)
```

However, I am struggling to add the random weights. My attempt is based on answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965360/networkx-python-how-to-change-edges-weight-by-designated-rule).

```
for u,v,w in in g.edges(data=True):
     w = np.random.randint(0,10)
```

I am doing this so I can explore and (hopefully) understand the networkx library.

My question has two parts:

**1. What is the best way generate a simple networkx graph for example purposes?**

**2. What is the best way to add weights to an existing networkx graph?**

Answer (score 9):

Just addressing question 2  (Q1 is very dependent on context)

you could use (I believe in both networkx 1.x and 2.x):

```
import random
#code creating G here
for (u,v,w) in G.edges(data=True):
    w['weight'] = random.randint(0,10)
```

The variable `w` is a dictionary whose keys are all the different edge attributes.

Alternatively in networkx 2.x you can do

```
for (u, v) in G.edges():
    G.edges[u,v]['weight'] = random.randint(0,10)
```

or in networkx 1.x you can do

```
for (u, v) in G.edges():
    G.edge[u][v]['weight'] = random.randint(0,10)
```

Comment: Consider mentioning `import random`.

Comment: @zubo Thanks.  Done.